# How to access useSelector value in event handler

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, closures

I'm picking up state value using `useSelector` for fetching the state variable and trying to access the same inside an event handler. But always getting a stale value.
Can someone please help me solve this problem?

```
import React, { ReactElement } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import {
  AMPLITUDE_SELECTION,
  FREQUENCY_UNIT,
  MotionUnitTypes,
  Actions,
} from '../../shared/features/workflow';
import AmplitudeUnit from './AmplitudeUnit';
import MotionUnit from './MotionUnit';
import FrequencyUnit from './FrequencyUnit';
/**
 *
 * @returns
 */
export function UnitsSelector(): ReactElement {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const frequencyUnit = useSelector(
    (state: any) => state.features.workflow.va.units.frequencyUnit
  );

  const amplitudeSelection = useSelector(
    (state: any) => state.features.workflow.va.units.amplitudeSelection
  );
  const motionUnitType: MotionUnitTypes = useSelector(
    (state: any) =>
      state.features.workflow.va.units.motionUnit.selectedMotionUnitType
  );

  // ######  This is showing appropriate value
  console.log(frequencyUnit, amplitudeSelection, motionUnitType); 
  const handleMotionUnitChange = (motionUnit: MotionUnitTypes) => {
     // ###### This is giving stale value. Always shows value of previous state
    console.log(frequencyUnit, amplitudeSelection, motionUnitType); 
    dispatch(
      VAactions.updateSelectedMotionUnit(motionUnit, {
        amplitudeSelection,
        frequencyUnit,
        motionUnitType: motionUnit,
        enableHarmonics,
      })
    );
  };

  const handleAmplitudeUnitChange = (value: AMPLITUDE_SELECTION) => {
    dispatch(
      VAactions.updateAmplitudeSelection(value, {
        amplitudeSelection: value,
        frequencyUnit,
        motionUnitType,
        enableHarmonics,
      })
    );
  };

  const handleFrequencyUnitChange = (value: FREQUENCY_UNIT) => {
    dispatch(
      VAactions.updateFrequencyUnit(value, {
        amplitudeSelection,
        frequencyUnit: value,
        motionUnitType,
        enableHarmonics,
      })
    );
  };
  return (
    <>
      <FrequencyUnit
        selectedValue={frequencyUnit}
        handleChange={handleFrequencyUnitChange}
      />
      <MotionUnit
        selectedValue={motionUnitType}
        handleChange={handleMotionUnitChange}
      />
      <AmplitudeUnit
        selectedValue={amplitudeSelection}
        handleChange={handleAmplitudeUnitChange}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

I understand that this issue is coming because of closure, but unable to get a right solution for this issue. Please help.

Comment: how are you using handleMotionUnitChange in MotionUnit?

Comment: @Federkun Its a simple function 

const handleMenuChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<MenuItemType>) => {
    if (event.target.value) {
      handleChange(event.target.value as MotionUnitTypes);
    }
  };


so when menu gets changed, it triggers this event and passes the value to parent function passed through props.
Sorry for bad indentation. unable to format this code snippet in comment.

Comment: "This is giving stale value." - but, why are you expecting `frequencyUnit`, `amplitudeSelection` and `motionUnitType` to have new values *there*? That seems perfectly normal (at least at first glance), given that dispatch hasn't been called yet at that point. What you should check for is if the `motionUnit` parameter has the new value. Given that outside of the handler you wrote "This is showing appropriate value", it seems that the values are updated correctly (these two lines of code *don't* execute one after the other as written, they are run at different times).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović when one of the unit gets changed, I need values of other units as well for state update inside reducer. That's the reason I'm broadcasting those other two values along with currently changed unit. 
Now current unit is giving me right value. However other two values are not giving me their real latest value. They are stale values.

Comment: What I'm saying is that those other values cannot magically update by themselves - you have to do something to change them. So in what sense are they "stale" ? Should the other values update when you change one of them? It's not clear from what you've posted how that happens. Is there some code that does that? What I'm asking is why do you expect these values to be different *in the handler* associated with a change on a single control? (So, not asking what you're trying to do, but what do you think the current code is doing that makes you believe that this line should show different values?)